# Safari - iPhone - WebApp crashes from unknown reason

Tags: javascript, dom, crash, mobile-safari, shadow-dom

I am currently working on a new frontend javascript framework. In past few days I refactored the DOM updater and few another code to look nicer and to get rid of some memory leaks when DOM elements stayed detached in memory.

Unfortunately, Safari on both, iPhone and iPad 2 started crashing now from unknown reason (the rest of browsers I am testing on are fine

windows:
   IE10emu/11, edge 14, chrome, opera, FF - latest versions

android:
   Webview 4, 38, chrome, opera, ff - latest versions

and there is no problem).

I tried to debug it with remote debugging using the Chrome on Windows and ios_webkit_debug_proxy but unfortunately it does not show anything to me.

I am almost convienced the problem occurs when I am working with the main DOM document or with the shadow DOM document.

What is strange: when I switch logging to console on (there is extensive logging
feature in the framework) just for the DOM updater module and use the remote debug feature, everything seems to be working fine (except its slow of course) and it does not crash anymore so I can't even see when it crashes.

As I have no Mac even the Apple dev license I am looking for help of somebody who owns Mac and have some dev experience. I would like to know if it is possible to somehow debug these kind of unexpected crashes or at least if it is possible to get the reason why it is crashing (some kind of safari log?) - memory leaks, out of memory... whatever what can help me to do some workaround.

The previous version was working fine. Compared to it I am not doing anything special, especially when manipulating the DOM but the code is reordered, placed in more functions / methods and optimized a little bit.

The working (less or more :) version can be found here: http://ajsfw.azurewebsites.net/

The problematic version can be found here: http://ajsdoc.azurewebsites.net/ with logging switched off (i can switch on if necessary)

Sources for the working code can be found here: https://github.com/atomsoftwarestudios/ajsdoc.

I can also provide new, problematic sources if necessary but I don't want to push them to the main until it will get fixed so I can i.e. fork or send it as  zipped package. The problem is it is a visual studio solution so bit incompatible with Mac at this time :) But I am pretty sure we can find a way.

The code is quiet complicated already and it will probably require bit of coopeartion by my side to find what is going on.

Hope you can help.

**Update (problem resolved):**

It was crashing on adding/removing "ontouchmove" event listeners.

I am using multiple HTML documents (document.implementation.createHTML) for templates and the main document (window.document) as a managed render target. When I loaded templates to the "shadow dom" using the innerHTML the ontouch... attribute assigned to the template tag was causing the problem so before I set the template innerHTML I rename it and later during rendering to the main DOM I addEventListener with the original name.

What is strange: before refactoring it didn't matter the event listener was registered in the template "shadow DOM". But I also added some new features so maybe one of them is causing it. Hard to debug, especially when the browser is crashing. Important is it works like charm again even with small complication in the code.

Results can be seen on links provided before, ajsdoc... is with logging so slower (slow as hell with IE10/11), ajsfw if unoptimized (unminimized) release without logging so faster.

Fixed sources commited if sbdy is interrested

Comment: I forgot to mention the metntion the reference guide have some problem after refactoring but it is not subject of the question.

Comment: Please consider raising a bug for this at https://bugs.webkit.org/ if it’s actually crashing the browser.

Comment: @sideshowbaker Its definitely a browser bug when it crashes :D I Have found similar issue they have had with the Polymer so crash during touchEventsChangedTimerFired is reported already by Google. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally obtained some crash logs from Safari.

It is crashing on adding "ontouchmove" event listener. Now I have to figure out why it didn't crash in previous version and register it in a different time.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to summarise where the problem was, I am using multiple HTML documents (document.implementation.createHTML) for templates and the main document (window.document) as a managed render target. When I loaded templates to the "shadow Dom" using the innerHTML the ontouch... attribute assigned to the template tag was causing the problem so before I set the template innerHTML I rename it and later during rendering to the main DOM I addEventListener with the original name.

What is strange: before refactoring it didn't matter the event listener was registered in the template "shadow DOM". But I also added some new features so maybe one of them is causing it. Hard to debug, especially when the browser is crashing. Important is it works like charm again even with small complication in the code.